# How do you use use RouteOptions in .NET Core 5 MVC? (to force lowercase URLs etc)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to use lowercase URLs in my app and I can see there's a RouteOptions object documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routeoptions?view=aspnetcore-5.0

But how do you actually ***use*** RouteOptions?

I thought it would be something similar to the below, but it just generates a compiler warning saying that app.UseRouting() doesn't take any parameters:

```
app.UseRouting(options => {
    options.<no intellisense>
});
```

So can someone please let me know where I can specify RouteOptions?

Answer (score 5):

You need to configure this in your `ConfigureServices` method, for example:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
});
```